# Why does Mathematica / Wolfram Alpha gives 2 different answers for these 2 queries?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I was assigned to find the integral of this expression:

$$ \int\frac{-5x^3+3x^\frac{3}{2}-2x^2-5x + \frac{3}{\sqrt x}}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$$

I did:

$$ = \int\frac{-5x(x^2 + 1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm{d}x + \int\frac{ 3x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(x^2+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm{d}x + \int\frac{-2x^2 - 2 + 2}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$$

And continued on from there.

Apparently, Wolfram Alpha (offline Mathematica as well) gives 2 different answers to the following queries:

1. [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%283x%5E%283%2F2%29+%2B3%2Fsqrt%28x%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29+%2B+integral+%28-2x%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29):

$$ \int \frac{3 x^{3/2}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}}{x^2+1} \, dx + \int\frac{-2 x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$

Which gives:

$$ 6 \sqrt{x}-2 \left(x-\tan ^{-1}(x)\right) $$

2. [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%283x%5E%283%2F2%29+%2B3%2Fsqrt%28x%29%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29+%2B+%28-2x%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29):

$$ \int \left(\frac{3 x^{3/2}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}}{x^2+1}-\frac{2 x^2}{x^2+1}\right) \, dx $$

Which gives:

$$ -2 \left(x-3 \sqrt{x}+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) $$

Which are almost identical besides the usage of $1/x$ vs $x$ inside $tan^{-1}$ and it's sign. My way led me to the 1st solution.

Which solution is correct? Is there anything wrong with splitting the integrals like that?

Comment: The usage of $\frac1x$ isn't the only difference here. There is another small difference between the two expressions.

Comment: The difference is that one has 2*arctan(x) and the other has -2*arctan(1/x) instead

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I've edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can understand the problem here when we plot the two functions together
$f(x) = 6*sqrt(x)-2*x+2*\arctan(x)$
and
$g(x) = 6*sqrt(x)-2*x-2*\arctan(1/x)$

In the plot, using some specific range the two functions take the same path
Check it

[graph of the two functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%206*sqrt%28x%29-2*x%2B2*arctan%28x%29%20and%206*sqrt%28x%29-2*x-2*arctan%281%2Fx%29)

Comment: The problem is the approach use to tackle the integral, because the results contains trigonometric functions which are biased with respect to sign.                                                     I used x-cas to integrate and got 6*sqrt(x)-2*x+2*arctan(2*sqrt(2/x))-6*pi as result after simplifying

Comment: That's what GNU Octave (with sympy) gave me as well. Do you think you can prove these trigonometric identities?

Comment: Yes maybe doing the integration in part would help and careful simplifying Integral( (3*x^(3/2)+3/(sqrt(x))-2*x^2)/(x^2+1) , x ) Becomes Integral( 3*x*sqrt(x)/(x^2+1) , x ) = 3*2*(sqrt(x)+sqrt(2)/8*ln(x-sqrt(2)*sqrt(x)+1)-sqrt(2)/4*atan((sqrt(x)-sqrt(2)/2)/sqrt(2)*2)-sqrt(2)/8*ln(x+sqrt(2)*sqrt(x)+1)-sqrt(2)/4*atan((sqrt(x)+sqrt(2)/2)/sqrt(2)*2)) plus Integral( 3/(sqrt(x)*(x^2+1)) , x ) = 3*2*(-sqrt(2)/8*ln(x-sqrt(2)*sqrt(x)+1)+sqrt(2)/4*atan((sqrt(x)-sqrt(2)/2)/sqrt(2)*2)+sqrt(2)/8*ln(x+sqrt(2)*sqrt(x)+1)+sqrt(2)/4*atan((sqrt(x)+sqrt(2)/2)/sqrt(2)*2)) plus Integral( -2*x^2/(x^2+1) , x ).   Si

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to *graph* both solutions to check if they are the same up to an additive constant? (That means parallel graphs.)

Did you try to *differentiate* both solutions to check if they are both antiderivatives?

Comment: According to [this test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+-2%28x-3+sqrt%28x%29+%2B+arctan%281%2Fx%29%29+%3D%3D+differentiate+6*sqrt%28x%29+-+2+%28x+-+arctan%28x%29%29) the derivatives  are identical, but the graphs of the original integrals are different, as seen in the plots of both queries (links in question's text).

Comment: Are the graphs parallel on intervals where each is defined (do not include $0$ in the domain? That is, can you get from one graph to the other by adding a constant? The graphs of $x^2/2$ and $x^2/2 + 5$ are not the same but both are anti derivatives of $x$.

Comment: Well they are sort of the same, it's just that the constant that makes the difference between the two is different (I think) in sign for the positive and the negative sides of the X axis.

Comment: Well, you can't insist the constant be the same on *disjoint* intervals.  For example, the function $f(x) = \ln x$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x) = \ln|x| - 19873$ for $x < 0$ is an antiderivative of $1/x$ because $f'(x) = 1/x$ for all $x \not= 0$.  You have to allow addition by independent constants on different (disjoint) intervals where the function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$\bullet \tan^{-1}(x) + \cot^{-1} x = \frac \pi2$

$\bullet\tan^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases}\cot^{-1}(\frac1x) &x>0\\ \cot^{-1}(\frac1x)-\pi &x<0\end{cases}$

$\bullet$ Indefinite integral represents a family of curves which vary by a constant.